# Generate 10 random numbers from 1 to 100 using array

Tags: c++, arrays

This is what i got so far:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    int array[10], i;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) : 
        [i] = rand()%100+1; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, i am very confuse about array and i dont understand how to generate random number without duplication with array.

Comment: Does your code compile ?

Comment: @NipunTalukdar [No!](http://ideone.com/WePcSR)

Comment: you really should go search the web (all the answers are on the web!)

Comment: What about fixing `for(int i=0; i<100; i++): [i] = rand()%100+1;` to `for(int i=0; i<100; i++) { array[i%10] = rand()%100+1; }` in 1st place?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you want N random numbers from a set without duplication, consider shuffling that set and then picking the first N elements. Then you don't have to keep track of which items have already been seen.

Answer (score 2):

There are "fancier" ways to do this, but keeping it as simple as possible:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int array[10];
    bool used[101] = {false};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        do
        {
             array[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        } while (used[array[i]);
        used[array[i]] = true;
    }
}
```

Note your `for` loop test was `i<100` which went off the end of the 10-element array!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't have the i declared in two places. That would produce a possible source of error.

Second of all, you should replace the ":" after the for loop with a "{". That would be the second possible source of error.

Third of all, there is something wrong with "[i] = rand()%100+1; ". I would recommend you to figure this one out on your own.

Also, please put out your entire code next time as it is essential for coders like me to see the entire thing so that debugging would be easier. (I know that the code is probably not complete since "int array[10] is not used.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to generate random numbers from a range of numbers without any duplicates you essentially have a very similar situation to shuffling a deck of cards and dealing them out. This is because you have a finite set of values that can be generated and once you use one you can't use it again. One way of solving this problem is to put all the possible values into an array then shuffle the array, you can "pop" off elements from the array by changing which index you access (just like "popping" a card off the deck of cards) and the generated values will come out in a random order without any duplication taking place. If the additional overhead of shuffling the array is fine then this approach is one of the conceptually easiest to get right. (If you only need a very small number of elements and you have a very large array then performing a random shuffle on the entire array is generally going to be expensive relative to other options)

As for doing this in modern c++ there's a bunch of really nice library functions (that are statistically better than `rand()`) to do this for you without having to deal with all the nasty things that are usually involved in random number generation.

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
         v.push_back(i);
    }

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());

    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), generator);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.begin()+10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

See this in action here: http://ideone.com/UerZQn

If you need to generate values without modifying an array see [TonyD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27221195/296460) for one approach.

Comment: Note: the loop to initialize `v` can be replaced by `std::itoa`.